# AngularJS animation not triggering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

I'm making a basic AngularJS application. Now I want to do an animation between my views. But it won't work, the animation is not triggering. [I followed the tutorial on the AngularJS website](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate). I'm probably missing something, I also have no errors in my console.

router.js

```
(function (app) {
    app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/home', {
            controller: 'homeController',
            templateUrl: 'home.html'
        }).when('/product', {
            controller: 'productController',
            templateUrl: 'products.html'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });
    });

}(angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])));
```

homeController.js (productcontroller is basically the same)

```
(function (app) {

    var homeController = function ($scope) {
        $scope.title = "Test";
    }

    app.controller('homeController', ["$scope", homeController]);

}(angular.module('myApp')));
```

I registered my module in app.js:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
}());
```

In my index.html file I include these resources:

```
<script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="myApp/app.js"></script>
<script src="myApp/router.js"></script>
<script src="myApp/controllers/homeController.js"></script>
<script src="myApp/controllers/productController.js"></script>
```

I think this setup is ok, everything works except the animation. I'm doing the animation in index.html as follows:

```
<style type="text/css">
.reveal-animation.ng-enter {
    -webkit-animation: enter_sequence 1s linear; /* Safari/Chrome */
    animation: enter_sequence 1s linear; /* IE10+ and Future Browsers */
}
@-webkit-keyframes enter_sequence {
    from { opacity:0; }
    to { opacity:1; }
}
@keyframes enter_sequence {
    from { opacity:0; }
    to { opacity:1; }
}
</style>

<div ng-view class="reveal-animation"></div>
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong to make these animations work.

Version: Angular version: 1.2.5 singularity-expansion

Browser: tested in Chrome, FF and IE

Comment: Do you have the ng-animate module included?

Comment: Yes as you can see in app.js: angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);

Comment: Ahh, okay. Can't see anything obvious here, could you make a fiddle?

Comment: HMM, interesting, I can't seem to find anything out of the ordinary either ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

app.js:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate','ngRoute']);//add all dependencies at once.
}());
```

route.js:

```
(function (app) {
    app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/home', {
            controller: 'homeController',
            templateUrl: 'home.html'
        }).when('/product', {
            controller: 'productController',
            templateUrl: 'products.html'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });
    });

}(angular.module('myApp'))); //just retrieve the module.
```

The reason is `angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])` in your router.js ***creates a new module*** named 'myApp' ***overwriting*** the `angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);` you create earlier in your app.js.

> Beware that using angular.module('myModule', []) will create the
>   module myModule and overwrite any existing module named myModule. Use
>   angular.module('myModule') to retrieve an existing module.

From [Documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)

Comment: Thank you, I'm getting closer. Now I do get a console error in angular-animate.js: object [object] has no method 'classNameFilter'. Now I have something new to google, thank you for your answer. Will keep you guys up to date when I find the solution!

Comment: Problem solved: updated all angular sources to the same version (1.2.6).